# How can we pass And condition as slash( / ) in views contexual filter?

Tags: 8

I have allowed multiple values in contexual filter (has taxonomy term id). Content is filtering based on multiple taxonomies like 12,14,16 when we are passing term ids in contexual filter.

But how can we get the same result when we pass the term ids in such format 12/14/16?

Actually I am working on REST API and I have to create URL something like :recipe/term1/term2/term2

What I have tried:

```
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$view_id = 'rest_api_ravi';
$display_id = 'rest_export_1';
$filters = [
    'field_recipe_tags' => ['12' , '124'],
];
$view = Views::getView($view_id);
$view->setDisplay($display_id);
$request = new Request($filters);
$view->setRequest($request);
dpm($request);

$view->execute();
$view_result = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($view->render());

$view_json_decode = json_decode($view_result);

dpm($view_json_decode);
```

But it's giving no result.

Comment: Not sure you'd be able to as the / is used to determine each contextual filter item. So as you only have 1 contextual filter you'd need to keep it within 1 slash. You could maybe create a custom controller for your /recipes page and then just load the view manually in that passing the contextual filter in the required format

Comment: Can you elaborate more can you show me any demo ?

Comment: Well, just convert them to commas, `$filter = str_replace('/', ',', '12/14/16');`